# How to fit more operations to tab bar + navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I want to use Tabview for my whole app.  However in certain view, I have more operations than I can fit in the navigator bar.  So I thought of using Toolbar but toolbar should be located at the bottom, right?  Toolbar looks weird to be on top of the tabview, and hiding tabview for one view doesn't really make sense.  I guess I can go with more buttons in the main view, but any other alternatives?

What can one use to add more operation(s) to tabview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to keeping the UI simple, Apple recommends using a "More" button on the tab bar to fit additional functionality in on a tableview or some other NIB.

Additionally, you could always have another NIB that is hidden unless they hit a certain area or button and then it pops into view for controls, options, etc.